# Assignment of floating point number to integer element of struct

Tags: go, constants

I'm going through the Tour of Go and I'm confused by 4/27 (https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/4)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

func main() {
    v := Vertex{1, 2}
    p := &v
    p.X = 1e9 // <- this line does not produce a type error
    fmt.Println(v) // {1000000000 2} implicite conversion of int to float?
}
```

I would expect this in JavaScript but not a strongly typed language.   I must be missing something fundamental.

Comment: @Flimzy According to specification `1e9` is a [Floating-point literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Floating-point_literals) so OP is correct that implicit conversion occurs here

Comment: @AlexYu: In this context, `1e9` is an untyped numeric constant expressed as a floating point literal.

Comment: The confusing bit is that a floating point literal does not have floating point type (it has *no* type!).

Comment: @torek: It won't be confusing after you read: [The Go Programming Language Specification: Constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants). As usual, you can use the form that is most meaningful and convenient, For example for `byte`, you could write any of `'X'`, `'\n'`, `'\x7F'`, `0`, `0xFF`, `42`, and so on.

Comment: @peterSO: I insist that it's still confusing. It's like saying that balloons are made of rubber, green is a color, and green balloons are neither colorful nor made of rubber. It would be more sensible to just call them *number literals* rather than *floating point literals*, or—if the word *number* is in use—something like *gronkle literals*. Don't use the phrase *floating-point* when they are not floating-point. But this is merely a minor quibble. (Computer systems, and real life, are full of these little inconsistencies, but we should be aware that people find them confusing.)

Comment: Whether or not it's confusing is something to take up with the Go team; updating the Go language spec is not in the purview of the SO community.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
 p.X = 1e9
```

Is an [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments). Spec has the following requirement for assignments:

> In assignments, each value must be [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the type of the operand to which it is assigned...

And the following assignability rule covers the above assignment:

> - `x` is an untyped [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) [representable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Representability) by a value of type `T`.

`1e9` is an untyped [floating point constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Floating-point_literals), and the value is representable by a value of type `int` exactly, so it's all good.

It would be a compile-time error if it would be a typed constant, e.g.

```
p.X = float64(1e9)
// error: cannot use float64(1e+09) (type float64) as type int in assignment
```

Because the above assignability rule would not apply, and neither all the other rules.

Same goes if the untyped floating point constant value would not be representable by a value of type `int`, such as in these cases:

```
p.X = 1e99
// error: constant overflows int

p.X = 1.1
// error: constant 1.1 truncated to integer
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help a newbe.   Very clear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)
>
> A constant value is represented by a rune, integer, floating-point,
>   imaginary, or string literal, ...
>
> Numeric constants represent exact values of arbitrary precision and do
>   not overflow.
>
> Constants may be typed or untyped. Literal constants ... are untyped.
>
> A constant may be given a type ... implicitly when used in a variable
>   declaration .... It is an error if the constant value cannot be
>   represented as a value of the respective type.

---

> ```
> type Vertex struct {
>     X int
>     Y int
> }
>
> v := Vertex{1, 2}
> p := &v
> p.X = 1e9 // <- this line does not produce a type error
> ```

---

`1e9` is an untyped numeric constant expressed as a floating point literal.

When the untyped numeric constant `1e9` is assigned to an `int` variable (`p.X`, type `Vertex {X int}`) it given type `int` implicitly. `1e9` (`1,000,000,000`) can be represented as a value of type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

**The Go Programming Language Specification/Conversions**:

A conversion may appear literally in the source, or it may be *implied* by the context in which an expression appears.

**The Go Programming Language Specification/Conversions between numeric types**

2. When converting a floating-point number to an integer, the fraction is discarded (truncation towards zero).

Here:

```
p.x = 1e9 // it's floating literal with implied conversion by context
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

Comment: @Alex Yu: In this context, `1e9` is an untyped numeric constant expressed as a floating point literal.